# I am using gulp and node.js in a project and trying to rebuild it and then I encountered the error: did not found ''gulp-add-src"

Tags: javascript, node.js, cmd, gulp

While executing gulp file through node.js ,I was trying to rebuild my project and then I got the error attached in screen shot

[image]

Comment: Have you run `npm install` befor it?

Comment: I have used "npm install" and then pperform gulp in cmd then I got the below error:

Comment: Ok, maybe you nead to install the module in your project. You can look into the package.json file if exist the dependencie. If not exist you can follow the answer below.

Comment: I have performed the below steps:
"npm install"

Comment: I have checked and dependency for mejs has been included in package.json
I have performed the below steps in cmd:
1. "npm install"
2. gulp


we made changes in gulpfile.js for adding gulp.task for mejs. I am getting error when trying to load it in localhost. Error is given below:

"mejs is not defined in app_bundle.js"

Answer (score 0):

did you install this module ?

```
npm install gulp-add-src --save-dev
```

It's look like your require("gulp-add-src") in the gulpfile do not find this module.

perharps if you can,  provide your packages.json to have a better answers ?